# What are the rules to shorten phrases correctly?

Tags: abbreviations

I have a dilemma, I do not know how to shorten the expression, *room temperature*.
I used to write it as `RT`, but several times I've seen people abbreviate it as `rt`.

Which one is correct?

And what about *ultraviolet*? Why is it shortened to `UV`, but *visible*, shortened, is usually  written as `vis`?

What are the rules for shortening words?

Comment: Any initialism (be it "RT", "rt", "r.t."...) stands for "real-time" to me.  :P

Answer (score 2):

There are no strict rules. 
You can infer some rules from currently used abbreviations.

- **Room temperature** consists of two words - abbreviation **r.t.** is appropriate
- **Ultraviolet** is one compound word, **UV** is appropriate
- **Visible** is one word, **vis.** is appropriate

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](http://chemistry.about.com/od/chemistryglossary/g/RT-Definition.htm):

> 300 K is a generally accepted value for room temperature to simplify calculations. The abbreviations RT, rt, or r.t. are commonly used in chemical equations to denote the reaction can be run at room temperature.

[Thieme Publishing](http://www.thieme-chemistry.com/en/products/journals/synlett/for-authors/abbreviation-list.html) uses r.t for their encyclopedias. This appears to be the generally accepted convention, but all 3 versions mentioned above are commonly used.